# Access custom Performance counter of application via WMI

Tags: c++, wmi, performancecounter

is it possible to access custom Performance counter of my application via WMI?

Comment: i am able to find out the solution of accessing performance counter, i searched custom counter in window Shell and then utilized this Class to get performance counter in c# via WMI. Microsoft has provided an bridge between performance counter and WMI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i am able to find out the solution of accessing performance counter, i searched custom counter in window Shell and then utilized this Class to get performance counter in c# via WMI. Microsoft has provided an bridge between performance counter and WMI